# Better way to prevent Page reloading when submitting multiple forms at once?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently working on a making a reference UI using vue.js. To dynamically generate the forms to change the settings by reading from a settings.js, I iterate over it like this:

```js
template: `
      <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded ">
           <h2>{{settings.title}}</h2>
  
              <form v-bind:id="settings.formName">
                  <div class="form-group" v-for="input in settings.inputs" v-bind:key="input.name">
  
                      <label v-bind:for="input.name" v-if="input.label !== ''">{{input.label}}</label>
  
                      <textarea class="form-control" v-if="input.type == 'textarea'" v-bind:required="input.required" v-bind:maxlength="input.maxlength" v-bind:rows="input.rows" v-bind:cols="input.cols"></textarea>
  
                      <input class="form-control" v-else  v-bind:required="input.required" v-bind:maxlength="input.maxlength" v-bind:placeholder="input.placeholder" v-bind:type="input.type" v-bind:name="input.name" v-bind:id="input.name" >
  
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    `,
```

I want to submit all changes in all forms with one button click (tbh I'd prefer being able to just submit it by pressing Enter without an actual button, but the keyboard events in vue are deprecated) without the  page reloading. (I am not using jQuery) Thus, in my index.html, I do this:

```html
<div id="app" class="container-fluid bg-light">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 text-center mt-3">
        <h1 class="border border-secondary">Dash Test</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="settings" class="col col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">
        <card v-for="item in Settings.settings" v-bind:key="item.title" v-bind:settings="item">
        </card>
      </div> 
        
        
        <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="submitForms()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
      
      var submittableForms = [];
      
      window.onload = function(){
          
          
          for(item in document.forms){
              if(typeof document.forms[item].id !== 'undefined'){
                  submittableForms.push(document.forms[item].id)
              }
              
          }
      }
      
      function submitForms(){
          for(item in submittableForms){
             var form = document.getElementById(submittableForms[item]);
             form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm)
             console.log(submittableForms[item]);
          }
      }
      
      function handleForm(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          event.submit();
      }
    
  </script>
```

which I came up with after a couple of hours of trying different methods I found, and it works fine. However, I do know that adding an EventListener in a for loop - especially when it is going to be called multiple times - is NOT a good practice. However I have not managed to find another way around the problem.

What I've tried so far:

- Use @submit.prevent="myFunction" with vue, and handle the passing of values in the method section.
- Use "form.submit().preventDefault(); which someone said works, but it just gives me "this is not a
  function"
- use return=false; after calling sumbit(); as specified in other solutions on this site, which does not
  work either.

One last thing I could do is try and make it one form in split "Cards", which should circumvent this issue, but I'd still be interested in how one would do it the current way.

Comment: All this looks like a non-Vue.js way. You should collect all data to one place like some component `data` or even Vuex state and just send all data using something like `axios`